# Implement Django aggregate object that is not mapped to database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model query function written in a test as

```
contracts = Contracts.objects.all()
contractPlans = ContractPlans.objects.filter(contractnum__in = contracts)
parentorgs = Parentorgs.objects.all()


for plan in contractPlans:

    contractPlanTags = ContractPlanTags.objects.filter(contractnum = plan.contractnum)
    for planTags in  contractPlanTags:
        #do more stuff here
```

Is it possible to have a non database mapped object where I can put in specific fields from `parentorgs`, `contracts`, `contractPlans` and `contractPlanTags` to be sent to the view?  Essentially, I just want a plain old data object to be used as a container wrapper for specific fields over four sets.

Comment: Maybe you need Django [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: @AamirAdnan, thanks for the heads up, it looks to be what I need.  If you put your comment as an answer and it comes through, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need Django [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Remember Abstract Base Class is not database object and hence can not be queried also.